# How to update and Save Array object in MongoDB (Mongoose + MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, hapi.js, arrayobject

**I want to save the interview array object.
I want when scheduled round 1 occurs and their feedback too based on round 1, want to save round 1 data with feedback and round 2 data with feedback, and so on**

**interview array has two objects**

1. schedule (for scheduling the number of rounds)
2. feedback (for getting the feedback of every rounds occur)

**Here is my Mongoose Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const InterviewSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 30,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 30,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    gender: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    contactNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    profile: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
    },

  **// Interview Array Objects, Need to update and save**

    interview: [
      {
        schedule: {
          interviewerName: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
          },
          date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
          },
          mode: {
            type: String,
          },
          meeting: {
            link: {
              type: String,
              trim: true,
            },
            platform: {
              type: String,
              trim: true,
            },
          },
          round: {
            count: {
              type: Number,
              default: 1,
            },
            type: {
              type: String,
              default: 'hr',
            },
          },
        },

        feedback: {
          technical: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
          },
          logical: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
          },
          communication: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
          },
          comment: {
            type: String,
            min: 10,
            max: 200,
            default: '',
          },

          interviewStatus: {
            type: String,
          },
          recommendation: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
          },**
        },
      },
    ],


  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

InterviewSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
const InterviewProcess = mongoose.model('interviewprocess', InterviewSchema);
module.exports = InterviewProcess;
```

I have done the update part i.e  in the array object schedule round is updated with feedback
but I am unable to save the data, it just overrides the previous schedule.

**Here is code what I have done:**

```
static async updateSchedule(request, h) {
    try {
      const payload = request.payload.interview[0];
      const params = request.query._id;
      const interviewSchedule =
        await interviewProcessService.findByinterviewProcessId(params);
      if (!interviewSchedule) {
        return h.response({
          statusCode: MESSAGE.STATUS.ERROR,
          message: MESSAGE.ID_NOT_EXIST,
        });
      }

      let mode,
        meeting,
        round,
        technical,
        logical,
        communication,
        comment,
        interviewStatus,
        recommendation,
        interviewerName;
      if (payload.schedule) {
        interviewerName = _.get(payload.schedule, 'interviewerName');
        mode = _.get(payload.schedule, 'mode');
        meeting = _.get(payload.schedule, 'meeting');
        round = _.get(payload.schedule, 'round') || {};
      }

      if (payload.feedback) {
        mode = _.get(interviewSchedule.interview[0].schedule, 'mode');
        meeting = _.get(interviewSchedule.interview[0].schedule, 'meeting');
        round = _.get(interviewSchedule.interview[0].schedule, 'round') || {};
        interviewerName = _.get(
          interviewSchedule.interview[0].schedule,
          'interviewerName',
        );

        technical = _.get(payload.feedback, 'technical');
        logical = _.get(payload.feedback, 'logical');
        communication = _.get(payload.feedback, 'communication');
        comment = _.get(payload.feedback, 'comment');
        interviewStatus = _.get(payload.feedback, 'interviewStatus');
        recommendation = _.get(payload.feedback, 'recommendation');
      }

      const result = await interviewProcessService.update(params, {
        interview: {
          schedule: {
            interviewerName,
            mode,
            meeting,
            round,
          },
          feedback: {
            technical,
            logical,
            communication,
            comment,
            interviewStatus,
            recommendation,
          },
        },
      });

      return h.response({
        result,
        statusCode: MESSAGE.STATUS.SUCCESS,
        message: MESSAGE.ROUTES.SCHEDULE_UPDATE.MESSAGE,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return ErrorHandler.error(error);
    }
  }
```

**Want to Achieve:**
whenever the GET method is applied, I want to receive no. of rounds with feedback.

Comment: You need to insert a new `interview` object in the array of the `InterviewProcess` with `_id = request.query._id`. Correct?

Comment: @lpizzinidev Yes, But I am unable to do this. every time when the schedule or feedback is updated its generated a new id. and I am unable to reach that.  I am trying to access it like this.    **payload = request. payload.interview._id;**

Answer (score 0):

var update = {name: 'updated item2', value: 'two updated'}; Person. update({'items.id': 2}, {'$set': {'items. $': update}}, function(err) { ... Problem with this approach is that it updates/sets the entire object, therefore in this case I lose the id field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Alisha_Vashists I didn't get can you please elaborate more?